# post checkbox value taken from mysql on form submission

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I want to make simple registration system. User select event on which he want to register, set number of person to register and click submit. Next he is redirected to register page where system generate register-forms and modify query so records are added to table dedicated for event.

I have problem with submission of checkbox value's, i recive **Undefined index** error all the time.

Kindly ask for some advice

Here is code: (HTML)

```
<form action="register-form.php" method="post">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <tbody>
                <?php show_active_events(); ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12" id="counter">

            <label for="select">Wybierz ilość osób do rejestracji</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="person_number">

            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>

            </select>

        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary col-md-12 pull-right" id="event-table-btn" name="submit">Dalej <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**SHOW_ACTIVE_EVENTS FUNCTION**

```
function show_active_events() {
    global $conn;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE status NOT LIKE '0' ";
    $showEvents = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($showEvents)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td width="90%">

<?php
        echo $row['name'];
        echo "<br />";
        echo $row['date'];
        echo "<br />";
        echo  $row['time'];
        echo "<br />";
?>
            <div class="accordion">Szczegóły ...
                <div class="accordion-content hide">
                    <p><?php echo $row['comment']; ?></p>
                </div>    
            </div>

            </td>

            <td width="10%">
            <div class="ck-button">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="ck" name="event" id="event" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"><span>Wybierz</span>
                    </label>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php }}?>
```

**REGISTER-FORM.PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$persons = $_POST['person_number'];
$event = $_POST['event'];
echo $event;
echo $persons;
}
?>
```

Comment: function `show_active_events` doesn't have any return value!!

Comment: Why it should have any ? Only aim of this function is to create tables dynamicly based on mysql records. Can you please explain ?

Comment: Please remember that the will be no entry for: `$_POST['event']` if the checkbox is _not checked_ by the user. That is how you know it is unchecked! i.e. You expect it. If it is missing then is unchecked. code: `$eventCheckboxIsChecked  = isset($_POST['event']);`

Answer (score -1):

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="ck" name="event" id="event" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" checked><span>Wybierz</span>

    once embed this line of code in function its OK other wise go below
```

I am executed same your code with my db its working. I think you have mistake in $row['column_name'] .once check column_name

Comment: Nope column name is okey, values are not send to form when i press submit.

Comment: Hii Ganga, I am executed same code its fine. Once check data from table.I think  if there is a problem with data.